# why do we need $f$ bounded for uniform convergence?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

#### Theorem

If $f$ is a bounded measurable function, then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{f_{n}\}$ which converge uniformly to $f$.

#### Proof

Define $f_{n}(x) = \frac{m}{n}$ whenever $\frac{m}{n} \leq f(x) < \frac{m+1}{n}$.  We clearly have that $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ (if this isn’t clear, look at what value $f_{n}(x)$ is and in what range the $f(x)$ can be; $f(x)$ essentially gets “squished” between these two values, and $f_{n}(x)$ goes to this value as $n$ increases).  In addition, and here is the clever part, notice that for every $x$ it is the case that

$$|f(x) - f_{n}(x)| < \frac{1}{n}$$

which gives us convergence.  The fact that $f$ is bounded between, say, $[m,M]$, gives uniformity (why?).  $\Box$.

---

I don't understand why we need $f$ bounded for uniform convergence. Isn't it already enough that $|f(x) - f_{n}(x)| < \frac{1}{n}$ was independent of the $x$ value?

Comment: Your $f_n$ can fail to meet a condition of simple function i.e. being the _finite_ sum of scaled characteristic functions.

Answer (score 2):

Every simple function $f_n$ is bounded, so if $f$ is unbounded, $f-f_n$ is unbounded, and you can't have uniform convergence.

As said in the other answer, your proposed function is, in fact, not a simple function for unbounded $f$

Comment: A simple function is a **finite** sum of characteristic functions

Comment: I don't get the downvote here? The answer is correct. The range of a simple function is finite.

Comment: @copper.hat The question is "where does this break down for unbounded $f$?", and the answer to that is not that the $f_n$ remain bounded (and thus ruin uniform convergence), but rather that they stop being simple.

Comment: The question as I read it is why boundedness of $f$ is needed for uniform convergence.

Comment: @copper.hat I realised that once I read your comment. Alas, by then, five minutes had passed, and I am unable to retract my vote until the answer has been edited. Would it be right of me to do a minor edit in order to be able to retract the downvote, you think?

Comment: @Arthur: Of course.

Comment: @Arthur : no problem, I'll do a minor edit

Answer (score 0):

I will expand my comment just in case that you don't fully understand it. By definition, a simple function $s$ is a *finite* sum of scaled characteristic functions of measurable sets, i.e. $s$ is of the form
$$
s(x)=\sum_{i=1}^mc_i\chi_{A_i}(x)\ .
$$
Let us suppose that $f(x)=\frac 1x$ for concreteness. In your proposed example, $f_n$ would have to be an *infinite* sum of $c_i\chi_{A_i}$ since $f$ is unbounded. This is the reason why your constructed $f_n$ fails to be a simple function. The boundedness  of $f$ is indeed indispensable.